# Trying to get property of non-object/ Php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I can't seem to figure about what is wrong with this code. thank yu for your help.
 I am getting error messages:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/members.php

Line Number: 24
```

**My model:**

```
public function show_user()
{
    $this->db->select('');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('email',$this->input->post('email'));

    $q=$this->db->get('');

    if($q->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        $data = array();

        foreach($q->result() as $row)
        {
            $data=$row;
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

**My controller:**

```
public function members()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
    {
        $this->load->model('model_users');
        $data['member'] = $this->model_users->show_user();
        $this->load->view('members', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('main/restricted');
    }
}
```

**My view:**

```
echo "<p> Congratulations you are logged in!!</p>";
foreach($member as $row)
{
    echo $row->Name. "<br/>";
    echo $row->email. "<br/>";
}
```

So this my code. I want to display user information from database but I am getting errors. please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You only need to return `$q-result();`

```
 if($q->num_rows() > 0 )
 {
   return $q-result();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you my error was solved but I didnot get the output as i expected. I want the email and name of only that user who has just logged in instead i got output of all names and email of the database users....  can you help me in that??

Comment: @Sushmita, From your query ,You will get all users having the email address you proided will return

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your database looks like but I suspect this is because either the `Name` or `email` properties don't exist on the `$row` object.  Are you sure your field in your `users` table is called `Name` or is it `name` (lowercase)?  If its lowercase your code should be.

```
foreach($member as $row)
{
    echo $row->name. "<br/>"; //Changed this line
    echo $row->email. "<br/>";
}
```

Also your `foreach` loop on your model is a bit pointless.  You might as well remove it and just do

```
return $data->row;
```